# SQL Command error ORA-00933 when deal with three tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Get all vouchers from `CRS_T_RES_VOUCHER` where `IS_OFFLINE_BOOKING` is true and (system date - CRS_T_RES_REGISTRATION. `UPDATED_DATE`) > offline Cancellation Threshold

Offline Cancellation Threshold can be taken from `CRS_T_HTL_PARAMETER` table.
PARAM_KEY - IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD

```
 SELECT v.VOUCHER_NUMBER
FROM CRS_T_RES_VOUCHER v,
     CRS_T_RES_REGISTRATION regi,
     CRS_T_HTL_PARAMETER para
WHERE v.is_offline_booking = '1'
  AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TRUNC (v.updated_date) > para.param_value WHERE para.param_key = 'IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD'
```

I encounter ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Check your query, have writen twice "Where"

Comment: You need to code SQL in convention and format your code. So you can easily see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it 
need to deal with nested query

```
 SELECT v.VOUCHER_NUMBER 
 from CRS_T_RES_VOUCHER v, CRS_T_RES_REGISTRATION regi, CRS_T_HTL_PARAMETER para 
 where v.is_offline_booking = '1' and
 TRUNC (SYSDATE) -  TRUNC (v.updated_date) > (select TRUNC (para.param_value) 
 from CRS_T_HTL_PARAMETER para where para.param_key = 'IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is that you have two written where clauses twice. Change:

```
 where para.param_key = 'IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD'
```

To:

```
 and para.param_key = 'IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD'
```

According to your last comment, try this:

```
 SELECT v.VOUCHER_NUMBER
 FROM CRS_T_RES_VOUCHER v,
 CRS_T_RES_REGISTRATION regi,
 CRS_T_HTL_PARAMETER para
 WHERE v.is_offline_booking  = '1'
 AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TRUNC (v.updated_date) > 
 (select distinct TRUNC(para.param_value) from CRS_T_HTL_PARAMETER
       WHERE para.param_key  = 'IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD')
```

Please, note that the query above will work only if there are not several param_values for 'IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD' param key.

Comment: I need to get para.param_value  where para.param_key = 'IBE_OFFLINE_CANCELLATION_THRESHOLD' that para.param_value (Date) should match with that condition TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TRUNC (v.updated_date)

Comment: I see now. Can there be several values with such param_key in the para table?